# How do I make an empty view inside ListFragment resize automatically at all times?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

More specifically, I'm using `SherlockListFragment` inside a `ViewPager` and the following layout 
([full source](https://github.com/oakkitten/weechat-android/blob/418b17265f5297aad5ac8c21f147d4d39923063f/weechat-android/src/main/res/layout/bufferlist.xml)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        ...
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/filter_bar"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/filter_bar"
        android:text="..."
        android:visibility="invisible" 
        .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I open the application I see this:

[image]

That looks fine. Then I connect and open a filter, it's empty for now

[image]

Note that ListView gets resized just fine. Now I type in the filter to filter out everything:

[image]

Whoops! Action bar disappears from the display! However, **if swipe back and forth through the ViewPager and do it again**, everything becomes fine (and stays fine):

[image]

What could I do to make the empty view behave normally, just like ListView does?

Answer (score 0):

set windowSoftInputMode to the activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml . Something like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".controll.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```